# how to use different class function in java

Tags: java, class

Hi im new to java i am unsure how to use class function in java . my teacher gave us the point2d class and wants us to use the function in there. there is a function call distanceTo

```
// return Euclidean distance between this point and that point
public double distanceTo(final Point2D that) {
    final double dx = this.x - that.x;
    final double dy = this.y - that.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

i am not sure how am i suppose to implement this.  this is my code

```
public static int calc(int amount)
{
      for (int t = 0; t < amount; t++)
       {
          double current = 0;
          double x = StdRandom.random();
          double y = StdRandom.random();
          Point2D p = new Point2D(x, y);
          if ( current < distanceTo(Point2D p ) )
          {
          }
```

i tried to use `distanceTo(p)` and `distanceTo(Poin2D)` and nothing works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public static int calc(int amount)` is `static`, and `distanceTo` is not.

For not being `static`, `distanceTo` requires an enclosing instance of an object, say: `new Point2D().distanceTo(...)`.

You can then call `distanceTo` to you some `Point2D` you already have, say `p2`:

```
p2.distanceTo(p);
```

Or you can try turning `distanceTo` into a `static` method, that would receive two points as arguments:

```
public static double distanceTo(final Point2D one, final Point2D that) {
    final double dx = one.x - that.x;
    final double dy = one.y - that.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

And call it using just:

```
distanceTo(p, p2);
```

<sup>PS.: as an alternative, maybe your solution is to turn `calc` non-static. You should try it, maybe.</sup>

Comment: If the function is made static, it will need to take two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a class function, you need a reference to an instance of the class as well. In this case something like

```
Point2D b;
p.distanceTo(b);  // Invoke distanceTo on b from the point of view of p
```

This is because your method needs 2 objects to be referenced. The invoking object `p` and the passed object `b`, in your function referred to as `this` and `that` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

To call a non static method of a class use the `.` operator.

To call `distanceTo`, use following syntax:

```
p.distanceTo(p);
```

if it was static, use class name with `.` operator

```
Point2D.distanceTo(p);
```